# opening doc and pdf files in terminal linux

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf

I have installed in my ubuntu 16.04 laptop , Abiword, libreoffice and xpdf. On GUI ,using either libreoffice or abiword , I can open my .doc and .pdf files without issues even when I start the terminal while still with GUI. However when I toggle into pure terminal console, using abiword , evince or lowriter commands to open any of the files, below are the messages I get. Can someone please help me fix this? even the xpdf command gives similar result.:

```
eugene@eugene-XPS-M1330:~/Documents$ abiword Auntiemi1.doc 
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

** (abiword:2020): WARNING **: clutter failed 0, get a life.
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No DISPLAY: this may not be what you want."


eugene@eugene-XPS-M1330:~/Documents$ evince Auntiemi.pdf 
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: "
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the document to open, if you are in a "pure terminal console"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean with “pure terminal console” – do you mean a TTY? Are you running a graphical session in a different TTY on this machine and want the programs to open there, or are you asking how to run those on a headless machine without a GUI session, e.g. a server?

Answer (score 4):

If you don’t run an X server there’s no display on which a graphical program can be displayed. You can use terminal programs, for `.pdf` there are [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) viewers available (though unfortunately not in the official sources):

- [fbida (fbgs and fbi](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/) – image viewer for the linux framebuffer with a wrapper script for viewing ps/pdf files, the whole suite is available as a `.tar.gz` on [the releases page](https://www.kraxel.org/releases/fbida/)
- [fbpdf](https://github.com/aligrudi/fbpdf) – a small framebuffer pdf, djvu, epub, xps, and cbz viewer
- [jfbview](https://github.com/jichu4n/jfbview) – PDF and image viewer for the Linux framebuffer

In the case of `.doc` files I would convert them to plain text, e.g. with any one of

```
libreoffice --convert-to txt example.doc
unoconv -f txt example.doc
abiword --to=txt example.doc
```

or [`docx2txt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/docx2txt.1.html) for `.docx` files. The resulting plain text file can then be edited using your preferred terminal text editor like `nano`, `emacs` or `vim`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this work around solution , However, please, how does one run the X server from the terminal console?

Comment: @eoo If configured properly you just need to run: `startx`

Comment: "However when I toggle into pure terminal console" he has one it seems. so the commands he uses  need to be told to open on the tty that has the desktop :+

Answer (score -1):

you can use this command to open all the files including .doc and .pdf files.
for example test.doc file
this command will open the file with libreOffice

```
xdg-open test.doc
```

Comment: I did your suggestion. This is what I got :

Comment: @eoo what did you get ??

Comment: eugene@eugene-XPS-M1330:~/Documents$ xdg-open Auntiemi1.doc 
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/run-mailcap line 528.
Error: no "view" rule for type "application/msword" passed its test case
       (for more information, add "--debug=1" on the command line)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found .......
etc

Comment: @eoo I think you don't have xdg-utlis, that contains xdg-open and I think it can open any file so hope this solution works for you .

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install xdg- utils ,it said it is already installed. I believe the system is pointing to an error at  line 528 of the file /usr/bin/run-mailcap and I need to understand what it is saying I should fix. Can I get any help with it? Thanks.

Comment: “`xdg-open` is for use inside a desktop session only.” – That’s not useful without a running X server.

Comment: tnx @dessert  so I think I didn't fully understand the question